# Can I use buffer as condition in TOSCA

Tags: buffer, tosca

I wanted to get the value from the page as a condition to run for the next step. For example, if the status shows 'On', then it should run the next test case. If not, then it should skip that test case.

I tried to put {B[buffername]} == "ON" in the condition under Properties, but it runs even though the condition does not match.

I'm quite new to TOSCA and there's not a lot of resources so I am asking here. If anyone knows please do help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with Tosca, using Buffers in Condition under Properties never worked, at best it is ignored, or simply make the step fail.

One way to use a buffer as a condition for a teststep is to use an 'If statement' with a TBox Evaluation Tool with your expression {B[buffername]} == "ON" in the 'Condition' section, and your test step in the 'Then' section.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Place Buffer in brackets, it should work
'{B[buffername]}' == 'ON'

As advice, try TBox Evaluation Tool for testing such things.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).